# Transpose grouped dates with MySQL

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have a table with column date; it contains records for some months, but not continuously. 
To see which months are present (present meaning 1 or more records in a specific month), I tried to make an overview. It should be something like this:

```
2013  Jan  Feb Mar -   May Jun // etc
2012  Jan  -   -   Apr May -   // etc
```

I can get all first days of the present months, but am stuck in how to transpose. If I do this:

```
SELECT
    IF (d = 1, month ,'-') AS Jan,
    IF (d = 2, month ,'-') AS Feb,
    IF (d = 3, month ,'-') AS Mar
FROM
    (SELECT
        MONTH(date) AS d,
        DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') AS month
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY
        month
    ORDER BY
        month) m 
GROUP BY YEAR(month)
```

If gives this as result:

```
 Jan  Feb  Mar
 -    -    Mar
 -    Feb  -
```

While it should give:

```
 Jan  Feb  Mar
 -     -   Mar
 Jan  Feb  Mar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let you do it without a subquery:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN 'Jan' ELSE '-' END) AS Jan,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN 'Feb' ELSE '-' END) AS Feb,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 3 THEN 'Mar' ELSE '-' END) AS Mar,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 4 THEN 'Apr' ELSE '-' END) AS Apr,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 5 THEN 'May' ELSE '-' END) AS May,
  MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 6 THEN 'Jun' ELSE '-' END) AS Jun,
  ... and so on through December
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Comment: Awesome, I was clearly thinking in the wrong direction. Thanks!